# If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ of index $2$ and $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ not contained in $H$, then $HK = G$

Tags: group-theory

Let $H$ and $K$ be two subgroups of a group $G$ such that $[G : H]=2$ and $K$ is not a subgroup of $H$. Then show that $HK=G$.
Now, since $HK$ is a subset of $G$ we need only to show that $G$ is a subset of $HK$. But how can I show it? Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $[G:H]$, $H$ has two distinct right cosets of $H$ in $G$: one is $H$, and the other can be written as $Hk$ for any $k \notin H, k \in K$. The right cosets of $H$ in $G$ partition $G$, so what can you say about $HK$, which obviously contains $H \cup Hk$?

Answer (score 1):

By Lagrange's,

$$[G : HK][HK:H] = [G:H] = 2$$

since $K \not\subset H$, $[HK:H] > 1 \implies [HK:H] =2 $, so $[G:HK] = 1 \implies G = HK$